# Laravel problem request an image data to store it somewhere else too

Tags: php, laravel

I ran into an issue I can't fix by my own for now 2 days.

I am using laravel and creating a post:

There I'm creating the post and also want to choose in my view-layer in my browser which photo I want to select. It shall be selected and also be stored in my posts database. 
You see the code of my PostController.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate posted form data
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|unique:posts|min:5|max:100',
            'content' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000',
        ]);

         $data['title'] = $request->title;
        $data['content'] = $request->content;
        $data['image_gallery'] = $request->path;


        // Create and save post with validated data
        $post = Post::create($validated);


        // Redirect the user to the created post with a success notification
        return redirect(route('posts.index'))->with('notification', 'Post erstellt');
    }
```

And there the code of my post create view:

```
    <label class="label">Beitragsbild: </label>
    <div class="field">
            <select id="id_select2_example" style="width: 220px;">
                    @foreach($images as $image)
                        <option data-img_src="/image/{{ "$image->id" }}">{{ $image->title }}</option>
                    @endforeach
            </select>
    </div>
```

and this is the error from the browser, but I cant make any use out of it.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'image_gallery_id' doesn't
>   have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `content`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values

I would really appreciate it if I can get some tips/further help!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, _in text form_, and properly formatted. _Do not_ just show images of code.

Comment: It seems there is some side effect when you create a Post which is not directly visible on the code you posted. The error could be translated as `image_gallery_id` is required, you have not included it and does not have a default value therefore I cannot store this data. Have a look in your code or database tables where this `image_gallery_id` is used.

Comment: My database DBeaver image table is named: image_gallery and in this table I've: id, title, size, extension, path, created_at, updated_at (I use path because we want to store the images not on the webspaces)

The database "posts" is for the posts and includes: id, image_gallery_id, title, content, created_at and updated_at

Comment: How you store your image file ?? WHat about the file move command ?